# How to find the script that writes in the log

Tags: servicenow

I need help finding a script that writes to the log with "information" level. only appears in the "source" field of the log the option " *** script "

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you are looking for some kind of stacktrace for the log, this does not exist. Unless you put where the log is coming from in the message, the closest you will get to is from which scope it is coming.

You could try and do contains searches on script_include and business rule tables to find if your log message is in there.